# Keep remote Hyper-v hosts in manager on close

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012, windows-8.1, windows

I have a windows 8.1 machine that I have installed the Hyper-v role on. We also have a couple of 2012 servers running hyper-v.
I am currently managing them from my PC to make life easier.

When I connect to a remote host, I can see all of the VMs. However, when I close the manager, the connection to that host is not remembered, meaning when I next open it, I have to manually re-connect.

Not the end of the world, but was just wondering if there was a way to make the manager keep these connections as persistent so I don't have to go through this process on every start up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because the MMC provided by Microsoft you are launching is read-only. Create your own MMC that can save your changes:

1. In the Start menu, type MMC and press enter.
2. From the File menu, pick Add/Remove Snap-in.
3. Add the Hyper-V Manager Span-In.
4. Click OK.
5. Add all of your Hyper-V servers.
6. Close and save your MMC.

Comment: Have created one with a few different snap-ins, Exchange, Hyper-V and AD UAC. I have added two hyper-v hosts, and saved the mmc. When reopening, it only has my local hyper-v host listed, and not the remote ones I added previously.

Comment: Hmmm, ignore that. It seems that if I go to file, save as... it does not save the remote hosts. If I add the hosts, then just close the console, saying yes to save when prompted, it saved it.

Comment: Did you happen to set the Console Mode to User instead of Author?

Comment: I don't think so, i'm pretty sure it is in Author mode.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue on my Windows 8.1 machine as well, it may be because I have the Client Hyper-V role installed, but I was able to 'get around' the issue by loading up the Hyper-V Manager, connecting each of the servers I wanted, then right-clicking on each one and selecting 'Remove Server', then when it asks, select 'Connect' (to essentially reconnect the next time it's loaded).   Do this for all of the servers you've added, then close and re-open the Hyper-V manager, hopefully that'll work for you.

I've also noticed that the issue can return if I close and reopen the Hyper-V manager to quickly.  It's like it hasn't fully closed down when it opens it back up and forgets some stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Resolution same as JackD above, except on Windows 10 machine. I had to do the add, remove server, tell it to reconnect next time.  Otherwise it would not save the list.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the way I did this was to check Connect as another user in the Select Computer window, click Set User, enter the User name and Password and check Remember me.

The key is to check Remember me, otherwise the server won’t appear the next time you start Hyper-V Manager.

Answer (score -2):

does anyone know a CMDlet for a Hyper-V Host to connect automatically to the other Hyper-V Hosts? Because I did not find any script in the internet until now.

But have a closer look to this config file:

C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Hyper V\
Client\1.0\virtmgmt.VMBrowser.config

Close Hyper-V Manager, save the config and in the future use copy+paste to replace the config with the right one. Or edit security properties to read-only. This works well.